# Fix: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer trying to multiply across columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table dataframe that has one column of names and 4 columns of int64.

```
issuer = pos.pivot_table(index="Issuer", columns="AssetType", 
values="MarketValue", aggfunc=np.sum)
```

I need to find all rows where any combo of the numbers has a positive int and a negative int.

I've tried two ways to solve this. First the long way of def product_all and using itertools.product as I go through each row/combo.

```
def product_all(row):
    list_iter = list(row)
     for x, y in itertools.product(list_iter, repeat=2):
        if x*y >= 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The other was just using .any() and looking for values > and < 0.

```
issuer = issuer[((issuer[col] > 0).any()) & ((issuer[col] < 0).any())]
```

Here is the head() of my df

```
AssetType                    Bond  CDS  Equity         Loan
Issuer                                                     
Name1                         0.0 -0.0     0.0   6900238.93
Name2                         0.0 -0.0     0.0  12130000.00
Name3                         0.0 -0.0     0.0   8501753.71
Name4                         0.0 -0.0     0.0  25255509.41
Name5                         0.0 -0.0     0.0  21746971.29
```

When I run both i get the same error:
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

When i print x,y i get the exact combos im expecting. Not sure where my code is breaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `any` along `axis=1`.

Try:

```
issuer[issuer.gt(0).any(axis=1) & issuer.lt(0).any(axis=1)]
```